# decorator to generate new classes into namespace

Tags: python, decorator

The specific use case I need it for is to deprecate class names.

Suppose we have class `A` in an earlier version and we want to deprecate its name but keep backwards compatibility:

```
class A(B):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        warnings.warn('deprecation!')
        super(A, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

... and B now has the correct implementation.

When we create a class `A`, we will run into a deprecation warning here. We can also use the `deprecated` module for decorators on `__init__`.

However, I want to skip this process and write less code, and hopefully achieve something like:

```
@deprecated_alias('A')
class B:
    # ... do something
```

Can I somehow inject the classname into the module-level namespace so that I can use `A` like this?

Comment: But, do you have to? You can just do `A = B` in `__init__`

Comment: Is there a reason not to do: `@deprecates(A)` or conversely: `@deprecated_by(B)`

Comment: No reason really. That was just an implementation specific detail that I'm OK with either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this is not exactly what you asked for, it is substantially less magical and ultimately the same number of lines of code. It is also far more explicit:

```
import warnings

def deprecated(DeprecatedByClass):
    class Deprecated(DeprecatedByClass):
        def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
            warnings.warn("deprecation!")
            return super(Deprecated, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

    return Deprecated
```

You can then use this like so:

```
class B:
    pass

A = deprecated(B)
```

Comment: `functools.wraps` is inappropriate here. Other than that, good answer.

Comment: Good answer, but I think you should not use the same name (`cls`) for two different things here.  It confuses matters unnecessarily.

Answer (score 4):

> Can I somehow inject the classname into the module-level namespace so that I can use A like this?

Yes.  The class decorator should:

- create a new type, with overridden `__init__` method, using the 3-argument invocation of `type`
- get the module of the original class, `sys.modules[original_class.__module__]`
- bind the new class in the module namespace, using `setattr`
- return the original class unchanged

Example:

```
import sys

def deprecated_alias(name):
    def decorator(class_):
        mod = sys.modules[class_.__module__]
        if hasattr(mod, name):
            raise Exception('uhoh, name collision')
        NewClass = type(name, (class_,), {'__init__': ...})
        setattr(mod, name, NewClass)
        return class_
    return decorator

@deprecated_alias('A')
class B:
    pass
```

**I don't recommend this approach** - too much magic.  It will confuse IDEs and break autocompletion.

A less magical approach, perhaps?  This could also be made into a decorator, and use `__subclasscheck__`/`__subclasshook__` if you need to control the finer details of inheritance.

```
class A(B):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        warnings.warn('deprecation!')
        return B(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Even though `globals` here may be the "wrong" `globals`, I'm not sure that the decorator will have to be much more complicated than `def deprecated_alias(old_name):
    def inner(cls):
        globals()[old_name] = cls
        return cls
    return inner`

Comment: Dunno. Wasn't me, and I've upvoted now that the `globals` thing is fixed.

Comment: A metaclass would clean this up, though I'm still not 100% sure what the OP needs exactly.